# What is the purpose of resonators in quantum circuits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, resonance, microwaves, cavity-qed

I have been studying about quantum circuits, and I have come across resonators or microwave resonators multiple times. I do have a vague idea about them but I am not able to understand what is their basic purpose in quantum circuits and how to deploy them in the circuits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resonators change time scales and coupling strengths by confining the electromagnetic field. Say you have your circuit or waveguide and you want to couple to an artificial atom. If you just let them do their thing, your coupling strength will be weak (an excitation is more likely to pass by than to excite the artificial atom). If you employ a resonator, you can reach strong coupling (an excitation is more likely to excite the atom than to pass by) and in addition you can tune the parameters.

For further details on the regimes reached in such resonators see [What are the "strong", "ultrastrong" and "deep strong" coupling regimes of the Rabi model?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86288/what-are-the-strong-ultrastrong-and-deep-strong-coupling-regimes-of-the-r)